# Decrypting PgP Encrypted File

Tags: java, public-key-encryption, public-key, pgp, secret-key

I am currently working on a PgPEncryptionService and am successfully able to encrypt the file with my pub keys. The issue I am facing is with decryption.

I am currently receiving this error when running my test case for my decrypting methods.

```
[main] INFO com.rxbenefits.service.impl.PGPEncryptionService - Secret key algorithm: 9

org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPException: unknown hash algorithm: 8

    at org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPUtil.getS2kDigestName(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPUtil.makeKeyFromPassPhrase(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPSecretKey.extractKeyData(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPSecretKey.extractPrivateKey(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPSecretKey.extractPrivateKey(Unknown Source)
    at com.rxbenefits.service.impl.PGPEncryptionService.findSecretKey(PGPEncryptionService.java:102)
    at com.rxbenefits.service.impl.PGPEncryptionService.decryptFile(PGPEncryptionService.java:132)
    at com.rxbenefits.service.impl.PGPEncryptionServiceTest.testFileEncryption(PGPEncryptionServiceTest.java:55)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner$1$1.evaluate(DefaultInternalRunner.java:54)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
```

And when running in debug I can see values are coming through fine....and the only thing I can find in the debugger for algorithm 9 is the one pictured below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1Tav.png)

Anyways. I am at a loss as to what I am doing wrong. I have generated these keys myself, and am able to encrypt with the pub key...but for some reason decryption is kicking my butt. Below are the two methods I am using to decrypt.

**This is the Decryption Method**

```
    /**
     * decrypt the passed in message stream
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static void decryptFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out, InputStream keyIn, char[] passwd) throws Exception
    {
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
        in = org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPUtil.getDecoderStream(in);
        PGPObjectFactory pgpF = new PGPObjectFactory(in);
        PGPEncryptedDataList enc;
        Object o = pgpF.nextObject();
        // the first object might be a PGP marker packet.
        if (o instanceof PGPEncryptedDataList)
        {
            enc = (PGPEncryptedDataList) o;
        }
        else
        {
            enc = (PGPEncryptedDataList) pgpF.nextObject();
        }
        // find the secret key
        Iterator<PGPPublicKeyEncryptedData> it = enc.getEncryptedDataObjects();
        PGPPrivateKey sKey = null;
        PGPPublicKeyEncryptedData pbe = null;
        while (sKey == null && it.hasNext())
        {
            pbe = it.next();
            sKey = findSecretKey(keyIn, pbe.getKeyID(), passwd);
        }
        if (sKey == null)
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Secret key for message not found.");
        }
        InputStream clear = pbe.getDataStream(sKey, "BC");
        PGPObjectFactory plainFact = new PGPObjectFactory(clear);
        Object message = plainFact.nextObject();
        PGPObjectFactory pgpFact = null;
        if (message instanceof PGPCompressedData)
        {
            PGPCompressedData cData = (PGPCompressedData) message;
            pgpFact = new PGPObjectFactory(cData.getDataStream());
            message = pgpFact.nextObject();
        }
        if (message instanceof PGPLiteralData)
        {
            PGPLiteralData ld = (PGPLiteralData) message;
            InputStream unc = ld.getInputStream();
            int ch;
            while ((ch = unc.read()) >= 0)
            {
                out.write(ch);
            }
        }
        else if (message instanceof PGPOnePassSignatureList)
        {
            PGPOnePassSignatureList p1 = (PGPOnePassSignatureList) message;

            PGPOnePassSignature ops = p1.get(0);

            PGPLiteralData ld = (PGPLiteralData) pgpFact.nextObject();

            InputStream unc = ld.getInputStream();
            int ch;
            while ((ch = unc.read()) >= 0)
            {
                out.write(ch);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new PGPException("Message is not a simple encrypted file - type unknown.");
        }
        if (pbe.isIntegrityProtected())
        {
            if (!pbe.verify())
            {
                throw new PGPException("Message failed integrity check");
            }
        }
    }
```

**This is the method being used to get the secret key**

```
private static PGPPrivateKey findSecretKey(InputStream keyIn, long keyID, char[] pass) throws IOException, PGPException, NoSuchProviderException {
        PGPSecretKeyRingCollection pgpSec = new PGPSecretKeyRingCollection(org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPUtil.getDecoderStream(keyIn));
        PGPSecretKey pgpSecKey = pgpSec.getSecretKey(keyID);

        if (pgpSecKey == null) {
            return null;
        }

        log.info("Secret key algorithm: " + pgpSecKey.getKeyEncryptionAlgorithm());

        return pgpSecKey.extractPrivateKey(pass, "BC");
    }
```

**This is my unit test for the above**

```
       @Test
        public void testFileEncryption() throws Exception {
            // create unencrypted file
        String tempPath = "temp";
        FileRepo fileRepo = new FileRepo();
        fileRepo.setEncryptionKeyNo(123L);

        // Create the unencrypted file
        File unencryptedFile = new File("unencrypted.txt");
        try (PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(unencryptedFile)) {
            writer.println("Hello, world!");
        }

        // Encrypt the file
        File encryptedFile = new File(tempPath + unencryptedFile.getName() + ".pgp");
        File encryptedResult = new File("encrypted.txt");
        try (OutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(encryptedFile));
             FileInputStream publicKeyStream = new FileInputStream(publicKey)) {
            encryptFile(out, unencryptedFile.getPath(), readPublicKey(publicKeyStream), false, true);
            try (InputStream in = new FileInputStream(encryptedFile);
                 OutputStream outResult = new FileOutputStream(encryptedResult);
                 FileInputStream privateKeyStream = new FileInputStream(secretKey)) {
                // Decrypt the encrypted file
                decryptFile(in, outResult, privateKeyStream, passPhrase);
            }
        }

        // Check that the decrypted file matches the original unencrypted file
        try (BufferedReader reader1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(unencryptedFile));
             BufferedReader reader2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(encryptedResult))) {
            String line1 = reader1.readLine();
            String line2 = reader2.readLine();
            while (line1 != null && line2 != null) {
                assertEquals(line1, line2);
                line1 = reader1.readLine();
                line2 = reader2.readLine();
            }
            assertNull(line1);
            assertNull(line2);
        }

        // Clean up the files
        unencryptedFile.delete();
        encryptedFile.delete();
        encryptedResult.delete();
    }
```

The findSecretKey method is the one I am receiving the error at. Specifically when it's returning pgpSecKey.extractPrivateKey.

Things I thought were the issue:

Wrong password. (This is not the case. I have created 4 different key pairs with passwords of 12345 and none work)

Changing the algorithm being used while encrypting. (now using AES_256 and error still remains)

Comment: **What version of bouncycastle?** The last version with `makeKeyFromPassPhrase` in `PGPUtil` was 1.46 in 2011 (after that it moved to the decryptorFactory) and even 1.46 should handle S2K hash #8 = SHA256. (Note the _encryption_ algorithm is irrelevant, it's the S2K hash at issue. You could try changing that.)

Comment: bouncycastle 1.45

Work is pushing for me to use this version...I have tried to oush for 1.46...

Comment: Wow! I would push for something not more than 5 years old! But if you are stuck with 1.45, you'll have to create or convert the key with an older s2k hash. How did you create this key? In GnuPG 2.2 --s2k-digest-algo is apparently no longer configurable for keys, but it still uses SHA-1 not SHA-256.